# How can there be different tracks from optical media exposed to the PC?

Tags: optical-drive, optical-media, block-device, audio-cd

Ok so bear with me.

An Audio CD has different 'tracks', right? Not the songs, but like an audio track, a data track etc. Only the data track contains a proper filesystem (and normal block sizes) as we know it, but all tracks contain sequential digital data that could technically be represented by a bitstream. Correct?

So when I put a CD in my drive, CLEARLY the audio track is accessible (because I can listen to it, rip it with `cdparanoia` etc.). So obviously my computer is able to access all data on this CD, even in the non-data track.

But when I go to the raw device file, `/dev/sr0`, that file represents merely the data track stream, or so I'm told. So I can't just `dd` it and have a full copy that contains all information?

Then where the hell does `cdparanoia` get its information from if it's not exposed as the device file? And how do I create a full copy of a disc, completely agnostic to what it contains, file formats, file systems etc - just bit for bit so I can work on it later?

Comment: "… if it's not exposed as the device file?" – In general there is also [ioctl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ioctl). Specifically for CD, see [*Summary of CDROM ioctl calls*](https://docs.kernel.org/userspace-api/ioctl/cdrom.html).